# The aria hidden attribute appears to be auto triggering

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some divs with background color and i want to add font-awesome icon over it. The icon is not shown and when i inspect the elements aria-hidden="true" is added in the html  tag automatically... How can i deal with the issue.

```
<div class="">
  <div class="service-1">
    <i class="fas fa-coffee"></i>
  </div>
  <p class="mt-2 ml-4">
     Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

When i inspect the elements the  tag changes to the following:

```
<i class='fas fa-coffee' aria-hidden='true'></i>
```

The css for the elements are:

```
.service-1{
    width: 138px;
    height: 138px;
    background: #EDE10D 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.service-1 > i{
    color: #fff;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility

Comment: *"If your icons are purely decorative, you’re already done! - Our auto-accessibility automatically adds aria-hidden=true and role="img" to your inline SVG attributes so that your icons are properly accessible."*

Comment: aria-hidden means hidden to screen readers and similar tools. Not hidden in browser.

Comment: but how can i make it visible?

Comment: [https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/troubleshooting](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/troubleshooting)